# JavaScript math trouble

Tags: javascript

well i was trying to hack storm8 scripting but it didnt work and it was annoying triyng to get the elements, that the gist of what was going on here but people didnt like the question...

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: Please be considerate and responsible about posting code on SO. Especially without a direct question, this is way too cluttered to be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing strings, not numbers, so the greater-than sign doesn't even mean anything

Which is bigger: `'foo'` or `'bar'`?

Here's where the code lies:

```
var cur = cur.replace(/[^\d\.\-\ ]/g, '');

if ( cur > '120000000' ) {
```

You need to make `cur` an integer and compare it with one:

```
var cur = parseInt(cur.replace(/[^\d\.\-\ ]/g, ''));

if ( cur > 120000000 ) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to make "cur" an integer via something like:

```
cur = parseInt(cur);
```

(do this after your regular expression).

And, also, things will be clearer if you do the comparison with other integers:

```
if ( cur > 100000 )
```

rather than:

```
if ( cur > '100000' )
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion

```
var cur;
window.onload=function() {
  cur = document.getElementById('cashCurrent').innerHTML;
  cur = parseInt(cur.replace(/[^\d\.\-\ ]/g, ''),10);
  buyland();
  window.setInterval(buyland,10000);
}
function buyland() {
  var loc = "http://kl.storm8.com/investment.php?action=buy";
  switch (cur) {
    case 120000000:
      loc +="&inv_id=13&formNonce=830225979b229c99070b5c977881589902e3a86d&h=639c2ebe06c39653e524d7824ae90321ca059d00";
      break;
    case 40000000:
      loc +="&inv_id=12&formNonce=_____&h=44cf9659719e68235c28ce06bd95fbe28053ff43";
      break;
    case 20000000:
      loc +="&inv_id=11&formNonce=_____&h=e4c0907879c13443de5bbeca2ca4d660d7a29f6b";
      break;
    case 10000000:
      loc +="&inv_id=10&formNonce=_____&h=3a64458ec8513e34cade9e0381aacb811fbc528a";
      break;
    case 5000000:
      loc +="&inv_id=9&formNonce=_____&h=d99223e36f2beda4b0d6f1e4aa5de4431b06f7e0";
      break;
    case 3000000:
      loc +="&inv_id=8&formNonce=_____&h=e25e1171ffc602c54c7ec6a5743c754a9f59cf1c";
      break;
    case 2000000:
      loc +="&inv_id=7&formNonce=_____&h=bcbbb4c836cd4c4bd7c188759ed668f6a7a33af2";
      break;
    case 500000:
      loc +="&inv_id=6&formNonce=_____&h=fc88c8637b89db80d39d7c91309777e3d5672929";
      break;
    case 300000:
      loc +="&inv_id=5&formNonce=_____&h=14c124f2d90c6c1c587e3b22919a058e4461ae85";
      break;
    case 100000:
      loc +="&inv_id=4&formNonce=_____&h=8ee5449f5bbb4456bca49c440bd2c128a75e55e9";
      break;
    case 20000:
      loc += "&inv_id=3&formNonce=_____&h=e9a05fe805992a5a5222e1e3f65210dd5c8b413f";
      break;
  }
  if (loc) window.location=loc;
}
```